# How to display list of items that is in other sheet but not in the other?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

As the title says, I need a column to show what is not on a range(BASIS) that is in the other sheet(BASIS)

[image]:

I've been searching for hours now but only found the opposite results.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, please? You say you want to find things in "the other that are not in the other".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=FILTER(A1:A1000, NOT(COUNTIF({C1:C500; D1:D500}, A1:A1000)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=FILTER(A1:A, NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C1:D))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: wow! this works perfectly! thank you!